# What is the correct way to call a .dll library with namespaces in Node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, dll, dllimport, ffi

I have the attached error and I think that this is because the library is in namespaces. I tried ffi and ffi-napi:

[image: test 1]

[image: test 2]

Here is the library open with Microsoft Visual Studio:
[Open library from Microsoft Visual Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hHY13.jpg)

```
 throw new Error('Dynamic Symbol Retrieval Error: ' + this.error())
    ^

Error: Dynamic Symbol Retrieval Error: Win32 error 127
    at DynamicLibrary.get (d:\pruebas\leerdll\prueba-ffi\node_modules\ffi\lib\dynamic_library.js:112:11)
    at d:\pruebas\leerdll\prueba-ffi\node_modules\ffi\lib\library.js:50:19
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at new Library (d:\pruebas\leerdll\prueba-ffi\node_modules\ffi\lib\library.js:47:28)
    at Object.<anonymous> (d:\pruebas\leerdll\prueba-ffi\index.js:6:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:701:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:712:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:600:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:539:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:531:3)
```

What is the correct way to call it?

Comment: Please include the code as text in the question, not as images.

Answer (score 0):

It's not that it cant see the DLL or its namespaces, but it cant see the functions since you are using a managed code (C#). So the solution here is to expose the functions from that library using DllExport tool ([github](https://github.com/3F/DllExport/)) you can read their getting started [wiki](https://github.com/3F/DllExport/wiki/DllExport-Manager) for more information on how to implement it.